Flutter Create slide animation bottom bar (MFN)
enter image description hereWriting Your Own Flutter Study Notes: Step 1
CWidget is a library I use. It serves the same purpose as StatelessWidget.
I was looking for a slide animation bar library, but I couldn't find any that I liked, so I decided to create my own. I used GetX, and I'm happy to see that the slide functionality works correctly.
// stl widget 

class SlideBottomBar extends CWidget {
  SlideBottomBar({super.key});
  final homeController = Get.put(HomeController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenWidth = Get.width;
    // build container 개수 만큼 screen width 에서 나누기
    double buttonWidth = (screenWidth / 4) - 17; // (margin + padding) / 2

    return Obx(
      () => CContainer(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[900],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // 슬라이드 애니메이션
            AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              curve: Curves.linear, // without any residue
              left: homeController.sliderPosition * buttonWidth,
              child: CContainer(
                width: buttonWidth,
                height: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, // 슬라이더 색상
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CRow(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                _buildBottomButton(0, Icons.home, "홈", buttonWidth),
                _buildBottomButton(1, Icons.business, "비즈니스", buttonWidth),
                _buildBottomButton(2, Icons.school, "학교", buttonWidth),
                _buildBottomButton(3, Icons.person, "프로필", buttonWidth),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomButton(
      int index, IconData icon, String label, double width) {
    return CContainer(
      onTap: () {
        if (homeController.selectedIndex == index) {
          return;
        }
        homeController.selectedIndex = index; // 선택된 인덱스 변경
        homeController.sliderPosition = index; // 슬라이더 위치 변경

        print(index);
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            Get.toNamed('/');
            break;
          case 1:
            Get.toNamed('/b');
            break;
          case 2:
            Get.toNamed('/c');
            break;
          case 3:
            Get.toNamed('/d');
            break;
          default:
            print('Invalid index');
            break;
        }
      },
      width: width,
      height: 40,
      child: CRow(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(icon, color: Colors.grey),
          homeController.selectedIndex == index
              ? CText(
                  label,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

: Getx controller
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  final _selectedIndex = 0.obs;
  final _sliderPosition = 0.obs;

  get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex.value;
  set selectedIndex(value) => _selectedIndex.value = value;

  get sliderPosition => _sliderPosition.value;
  set sliderPosition(value) => _sliderPosition.value = value;

  PageController pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose(); // PageController 해제
    super.dispose();
  }
}

There's nothing specific to explain in words, but Stack Overflow suggests writing longer posts.
If any developers have alternative methods for creating a slide animation bottom bar, please leave a comment on the post. Thank you!
